# AADB2C90077: User does not have an existing session and request prompt parameter has a value of 'None'. 2

Tags: azure-ad-b2c, identity-experience-framework

I was working in our app and I got redirected to sign-in.  I had just signed in about 1 or 2 hrs ago.  I'm guessing something is not configured the way I expect w/ [Session Behavior](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/active-directory-b2c-token-session-sso#session-behavior)?

- Are the defaults the same w/ custom policies (using the [starter pack](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-b2c-custom-policy-starterpack))?

> **Web app session lifetime** (minutes)
>
> Default = 1440 minutes.
>
> **Web app session timeout**
>
> Rolling (the default setting)

Comment: When using custom policies, I use to add the session behavior section to my RP policy, with the desired values. I know you may be aware of this, but just in case, see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/active-directory-b2c-reference-manage-sso-and-token-configuration#session-behavior-and-sso, and an example I've published in my GitHub profile https://github.com/marcelodiiorio/My-Azure-AD-B2C-use-cases/tree/master/Configuring%20B2C%20as%20JWT%20issuer%20using%20OAUTH-OIDC

Comment: Thanks  @MarceloP.DiIorio-MSFT!  I’ve gone ahead and configured that.  Testing it out... still wondering what the default behavior is though.